# LED Remote, Isolating 2 channels

Tags: led, diodes, remote-control

I previously had a simple remote that allowed me to turn the LED strips on my motorcycle on and off when parked, which then I also wired in a separate relay so that the strips turn on with the ignition switch. The remote was switched on the positive line, so it made things easy. Never had an issue, it worked like a dream for the past 4 years.

I now have a 2 channel LED remote that has a function that alternates a strobe effect on the two channels. The remote is switched on the ground lines, not the 12v+. when I connect it up, and try the alternating flash setting, it doesn't alternate between the 2 channels, they both strobe at the same time.

I am trying to isolate the 2 channels using rectifying diodes, but I don't seem to have it right. I did up this diagram to show what I have now, thinking that the diodes would have worked in that configuration, but no joy. should the diodes be going on the 12v+ side?? Help me out please.  [image: Motorcycle wiring]

Comment: I confirmed with the supplier that the remote is switched on ground. That certainly threw me for a loop, because everything else in my experience has had the 12v+ line switched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your diodes appear to be connected backwards. Current flows from Anode to Cathode in the direction of the arrow, which needs to be towards Ground. I have modified your diagram with the correct diode polarities, and showing the complete circuit with what (I think) is inside the black boxes.

Two diodes between the LED strips and the ignition relay contact would probably be enough to isolate the LED strips, but the extra ones won't hurt.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for cleaning up the diagram Bruce. I may have put the arrows direction wrong (I'm a noob at the actual diagrams). I'm thinking I am going to pull it out onto the bench and do a mini mockup on a breadboard to give that a try. It should be easier than being hunched over the motorcycle.